# Cast Interface And Class Objects

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

What is the difference between cast object to interface cast object to class like this example.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    interface IAnimal
    {
        string Sound();
    }

    class Animal : IAnimal
    {
        public string Sound()
        {
            return "Animal sound";
        }
    }

    class Lion : Animal, IAnimal
    {
        public string Sound()
        {
            return "Roarrrrr";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Lion lion = new Lion();
            IAnimal animal = (Animal)lion; // variant 1

            IAnimal animal2 = (IAnimal)lion; // variant 2

            Console.WriteLine(animal.Sound());
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between variant 1 and variant 2 ?

Comment: I guess you get a compiler error, or at least a compiler warning like "use the keyword new for Sound if you intend to override the function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is in how the compiler checks that the casts are allowed.

In the first variant the compiler checks how `Lion` can be cast to `Animal`, then it checks how `Animal` can be cast to `IAnimal`. As both cast can be done safely as `Lion` is an `Animal` and `Animal` is an `IAnimal`, the compiler generates no code for casting at all, it's just an assignment.

In the second variant the compiler checks how `Lion` can be cast to `IAnimal`, then it checks if `IAnimal` is the same as `IAnimal`. As the cast can be done safely it generates no code for casting there either, it's also just an assignment.

As `Lion` is an `IAnimal` you don't need to do any casting at all, you can just assign it to the variable:

```
IAnimal animal3 = lion;
```

In that case the compiler will check how `Lion` can be cast to `IAnimal`, and as that can be done safely it doesn't generate any code for casting, just the assignment.

Comment: So there is no difference when I cast (Animal)lion and (IAnimal)lion to IAnimal object because the object is of type Lion right ?

Comment: @theChampion: There is no difference because both `Animal` and `IAnimal` can safely be assigned to an `IAnimal` variable. Once you have made the cast to `Animal` and `IAnimal`, the compiler doesn't care that the actual type is `Lion`. When you assign a reference to a variable, it's the type of the reference that determines if it can be assigned to the variable, not the actual type of the object that it's referencing.

Comment: Can I understand that this (IAnimal)lion is equal to this IAnimal animal = new Lion ?

Comment: @theChampion: Not at all equal, but I think that you mean the casting that is done in the two, which is the same. In both the `Lion` reference is cast to an `IAnimal` reference, and it's done by the compiler, not at runtime. The first is an explicit cast while the second is an implicit cast.

Comment: So the compiler understand this line of code IAnimal animal = (Animal)lion like this 

First - (Animal)lion is turned into Animal a = lion

Second - IAnimal animal = a ?

Comment: @theChampion: Yes, you can think of it like that. All the casting only goes on in the mind of the compiler, in the finished code the `Lion` reference is just assigned to an `IAnimal` variable, turning it into an `IAnimal` reference without any checks or conversions. The compiler does the checks at compile time, and determines that there is no checks needed at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
IAnimal animal = (Animal)lion;
```

there's an **implicit conversion** going on because `animal` is declared as `IAnimal`, and `Animal` is convertible to `IAnimal` (because the class implements the interface).

It corresponds to writing

```
Lion lion = new Lion();
Animal a = lion;
IAnimal ia = a;
```

All these conversions are possible.

However, you could also just have written:

```
IAnimal lion = new Lion();
```

On the other hand, if you had written

```
var animal = (Animal)lion;
```

`animal` would have been an instance of `Animal`.

Comment: Can I understand that this (IAnimal)lion is equal to this IAnimal animal = new Lion ?

Answer (score 3):

Literally there is **no difference** in compiled IL. but there exist an implicit conversion which is performed by compiler when you assign `Animal` to `IAnimal`. Compiler is happy in doing that because it knows `Animal` implements `IAnimal`.

Here's the IL which shows what I mean.

```
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Lion..ctor //Create new lion
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // store it in variable lion
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // load variable lion
IL_0008:  stloc.1     // store it in variable animal
IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // load variable lion
IL_000A:  stloc.2     // store it in variable animal2
IL_000B:  ldloc.1     // load variable animal
IL_000C:  callvirt    UserQuery+IAnimal.Sound //Call animal.Sound 
IL_0011:  call        System.Console.WriteLine //With the result call Console.WriteLine
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you are performing a explicit conversion to `Animal` and then an implicit conversion is taking place to convert it to `IAnimal` similar to `IAnimal animal = (IAnimal)(Animal)lion;`. The second example is simply performing an implicit conversion and, for all intents and purposes, you can remove the cast in the second example.